# Button Text Toggle is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

what i Need

- when click on view detail => show data.
- when data is shown then show hide detail.

html code

```
   <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="viewdetail" class="btn-primary" style="position:relative;left:20px;"
                onclick="
                $(this).find('.speakers').toggle(function() {
                    $(this).text('Hide Details');
                      }, function() {
                    $(this).text('view details');
                      });">view details


                <div class="speakers dis-non">

                </div>
                </a>
```

Error

```
      JQMIGRATE: jQuery.fn.toggle(handler, handler...) is deprecated
```

Comment: Referring to the documentation of jquery the `toggle` method with two handler callbacks is deprecated in 1.8 and removed in 1.9! http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Comment: It is not a valid HTML to nest a 'div' element inside an 'a' element. Checkout my answer for a working and valid example (fiddle included).

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove `.toggle()` and use `.text()`.

```js
$('#viewdetail').click(function() {
  var div_text = $(this).find('.speakers').text();
  if (div_text == 'Hide Details') {
    $(this).find('.speakers').text('view details');
  } else {
    $(this).find('.speakers').text('Hide Details');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="viewdetail" class="btn-primary" style="position:relative;left:20px;">
  <div class="speakers dis-non">view details</div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

check the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ronency/bLor3x6g/1/)

**HTML**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="viewdetail" class="btn-primary">view details</a>
<div class="speakers"></div>
```

**JS**

```
var button = $('#viewdetail');
var content = $('.speakers');
button.click(function(){
    var isOpen = content.hasClass('on');
    if(isOpen){
        button.html('Show Details');
        content.removeClass('on');
    }else {
        button.html('Hide Details');
        content.addClass('on');
    }
});
```

**CSS**

```
#viewdetail {}
.speakers {height:20px;background-color:red;transitions:all 500ms;}
.speakers.on {height:100px;}
```

Answer (score -1):

Then you could do it in a normal way by using [`jQuery.text`](http://api.jquery.com/text)'s `function` overload and ternary operators.

```
$('#viewdetail').click(function() {
    $(this).find('.speakers').text(function(_, txt) {
        return !txt.indexOf("Hide") ? 'Show Details' : 'Hide Details';
    });
});
```

Comment: !txt.indexOf("Hide") will never be true, because indexOf will return -1 if the "Hide" is not there... not false.

Comment: @Ronen check your facts. ! is a not operator and it works perfectly